# How can I stop Auto Layout from stretching the height of my popover when on an iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

On an iPhone 4 (or any iPhone/iPod device without the 16:9 iPhone 5 resolution) my popover looks great; not stretched at all and exactly as I intended.

[image]

However, on an iPhone 5 the popover is stretched:

[image]

And I can only assume it's because of a constraint with Auto Layout, but I can't quite figure out what is causing it.

When I select the UIView that contains all the controls in the window (and what appears to be being stretched) in Interface Builder these are the constraints it has on it (again, apologies for the height of the image, it has a lot of subviews):

[image]

I thought it was `Top Space to: Superview Equals: 103` but I cannot delete that. I promote it to a user constraint, then delete it and it just reappears.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode you can't delete a constraint unless there is enough constraints remaining in order for Xcode to determine the layout in Storyboard or IB, usually at minimum 2 constraint vertically/horizontally. So you will need to add a height constraint (2nd from the top) first before deleting the top space constraint:

[image]

This will give you a fixed height constraint that you want in the first place.